JSF is not reachable in my tomcat web-server
If I try to call my .xhtml page on my webserver, I get an 404.
My web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

My project structure:
enter image description here
On my container:
enter image description here
When I call "localhost/amazonlite/cart.xhtml" or "localhost/cart.xhtml", or "localhost/amazonlite/faces/cart.xhtml", or "http://localhost:8080/faces/cart.xhtml" I got resource not found.

The url-pattern for the faces-servlet should be simply *.xhtml for JSF to process all xhtml files on any path and then the url should be http://localhost:8080/amazonlite/cart.xhtml for it to work.
To reverse engineer the correct url to use from the deployment environment: The name of the webapp, 'amazonlite' in this case, is by default part of the url and the default port that Tomcat listens on for HTTP traffic is 8080.
The name of a webapp will by default and convention be the name of the war without the .war extension. So amazonlite.war becomes amazonlite.
For reference, the changed web.xml from the question:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
     version="4.0">
  <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
      <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>


Hey :-) With your solution, it does not work anymore. /faces/*xhtml enables loading the xhtml page on /amazonlite/cart.xhtml. I assume, that there must be some deeper problem with jsf on my setup. It seems, the xhtml is not loading correctly with jsf, because the jsf elements where not displayed correctly.
